# Is Android.net.rtp only for VoIP ppplication？

Tags: android, rtp

From API 12, Android have its only RTP package, which is android.net.rtp.

There are 4 classes in this package: RtpStream, AudioStream, AudioCodec and AudioGroup.

However, it seems that all those classes are only for VoIP application. I'm trying to stream some 'static' audio file (such as MP3 file on SDCARD) by using RTP protocol to VLC player and I find it somehow impossible by using android.net.rtp.

I tried this example: http://androidsourcecode.blogspot.com/2013/10/android-rtp-sample-receiving-via-vlc.html

The result is: The sound from the mic of my android phone was sent successfully to my MAC VLC player very well.

So, is it possible to stream 'static' file through android's native media decoder, and push decoded data to AudioRecord then again to AudioStream?

To make it simple, is it possible to make a fake microphone (MP3 file -> MediaPlayer -> AudioRecord -> AudioStream) pipeline?

Comment: AudioGroup only make a group of microphone(input stream), speaker(output stream) and AudioStream(transmit stream) which is a sub class of RtpStream. So it does NOT provide any API to attach other input stream.